# Eclipse IDE hieroglyphs

Tags: c++, eclipse, symbols

I'm trying to set up a C++ environment as a beginner.
Somehow the Eclipse IDE shows me hieroglyphs.
I haven't really done much yet, except trying out a darker theme.
Any idea what I have to do?[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wjdS.jpg)

Comment: What leads you to believe that these are "hieroglyphs"?

Comment: Have you explored the IDE's text encoding settings? What region are you in?

Comment: Looks like you got a file in an unsupported file encoding. Is this the auto-generated file from the Hello World default project?

Comment: I'm in German Switzerland. Yes, it's the default file.

Comment: Set it up on Linux. Works like a charm.